# How to auto login during scraping website process?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from a website with multiple pages (from page 1 to page 17) with the code (`for i in range(0,16)`). Below is the code that i am using and it works.

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

for i in range(0,16):
    URL = 'https://pvoutput.org/list.jsp?p={}&id=82699&sid=73313&gs=0&v=0&o=date&d=desc'.format(i)
    page = requests.get(URL)
    doc = lh.fromstring(page.content)
    tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')

    col=[]
    i=0

    for t in tr_elements[3]:
        i+=1
        name=t.text_content()
        print('%d:"%s"'%(i, name))
        col.append((name, []))
```

For example, in each page, there is a table, i want to scrape the data from row 4 of the table (the data here is the headers of table, just for now) (`for t in tr_elements[3]`) and save all the data of each page in array `col`

As the result:

```
...
1:"Date▼"
2:"Generated"
3:"Efficiency"
4:"Exported"
5:"Peak Power"
6:"Peak Time"
7:"Conditions"
8:"Temperature"
9:"Comments"
1:"Date▼"
2:"Generated"
3:"Efficiency"
4:"Exported"
5:"Peak Power"
6:"Peak Time"
7:"Conditions"
8:"Temperature"
9:"Comments"
1:"Don't have a login? Register in 10 seconds.  Forgot Password?"
1:"Don't have a login? Register in 10 seconds.  Forgot Password?"
1:"Don't have a login? Register in 10 seconds.  Forgot Password?"
...
```

The problem now is, when the program continue to scrape data in the next page, it starts to ask for login  before it continues.

Is there any method or way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to login to get the result from the last 3 pages. This site is using javascript objects as all most all those sites do that requires login. You need to learn selenium now as the same thing happened to me when i tried to scrape a site like that. Selenium is your tool for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks, i have tried to use Selenium and this problem is solved by using function click().